# RAZOR how to trigger an event when a user clicks on a component

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am new to RAZOR, I want to trigger an event when a user clicks on the RadioButton.

Ideally, it should dynamically show the selected value after a user clicked a RadioButton.

Questions:

1. How to get the selected value
2. How to trigger an event when a user clicked a RadioButton.

   ```
   @{
       Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
       Page.Title = "Contact";
    }

   <div>
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
            @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Male", true) Male
         </td>
         <td>
            @Html.RadioButton("Gender", "Female", false) Female
         </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
         @Html.Label(Request["Gender"] == null ? "No Selection" : Request["Gender"])
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do it with Razor, What you can do is to Create Radio Button Like this and Trigger any Action using Jquery.

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male <br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
```

You could add script **(assuming you can use jQuery)** on the page like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(':radio[name="sex"]').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sex',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { sex: $('radio[name="sex"]').val() },
            success: function (xhr_data) {
                alert(xhr_data.someValue);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Assuming you have an **action method** in the same controller as the one that generated your view:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult sex(string sex)
   {
      // do something awesome
      return Json(new { someValue = "testing!" });
   }
}
```

Comment: thx, but I want to lean new thing that's why I posted this thread. Could you please provide me some Razor code?

Answer (score 1):

razor has abandoned event drivers model,you can use a form sheet,when you can submit the form,you can get the result in controller

Comment: that's the answer I'm looking for. Please explain your answer, I am totally new to RAZOR, so I appreciate if you could provide me a fragment of code. I really need it. Coz I searched for hours and cannot find anything related.

Comment: btw, I am not using RAZOR with MVC. I am using RAZOR only. So is there any way to only use RAZOR to find an alternative of event-driver model? many thx